# D3DXPlaneNormalize only returns the normalized plane or also modifies it?

Tags: c++, directx-11

i'm a college student and i have a small doubt about a function in directx. I'm trying to apply frustrum culling and i need the normal of the planes of the frustrum.

I used the D3DXPLANE and with that the D3DXPlaneNormalize function to get the normals, but i also need the plane constant to check if and object is in the frustrum.

That function just returns the normalized planes or it also modifies them?

Comment: Read the manual? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205392(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As a note, ``D3DXPlaneNormalize`` is D3DXmath which is really old at this point, and is part of the deprecated D3DX library. You should probably be looking at something a bit more modern and supported like [DirectXMath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437833(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the legacy D3DXMath functions return a pointer to one of the input structures for convenience. As noted on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205392.aspx) documentation page:

```
D3DXPLANE* D3DXPlaneNormalize(
 _Inout_       D3DXPLANE *pOut,
 _In_    const D3DXPLANE *pP
);
```

> The return value for this function is the same value returned in the pOut parameter. In this way, this function can be used as a parameter for another function.

**Note that D3DX9, D3DX10, an D3DX11 are all deprecated. As such, D3DXMath is also deprecated. The legacy DirectX SDK itself is also deprecated**.  See [MSDN: Where is the DirectX SDK?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx), [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/), and [Introducing DirectXMath](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/)